# Formulas before the first line of a system

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

How can I make `\lambda_1:` appear on the same level as the first line of the system?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \lambda_1:
    \left\{\begin{alignedat}{3}
        e^{\lambda_1 x} &= e^{0x} &= 1,\\
        xe^{\lambda_1 x} &= xe^{0x} &= x,\\
        x^2e^{\lambda_1 x} &= x^2e^{0x} &= x^2
    \end{alignedat}\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you don't want the `lambda:` aligned with the peak of the { ? won't that look rather strange?

Comment: So how's the question completely different? I rolled back. If you want an answer to a different question, please don't vandalize and ask a new one. Have respect for the people that answered your question.

Comment: @egreg kinda differend, but the question is the previous.

Comment: @antshar ***Don't*** do it again.

Answer (score 1):

Quite strange requirement.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,delarray}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
    \lambda_1:
    \begin{array}[t]\lbrace{@{}l@{}}.
      \begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
        e^{\lambda_1 x} &= e^{0x} &&= 1,\\
        xe^{\lambda_1 x} &= xe^{0x} &&= x,\\
        x^2e^{\lambda_1 x} &= x^2e^{0x} &&= x^2
    \end{alignedat}
    \end{array}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please never mind such a requirement. I needed that for the oper purpose, but I thought this example would make it easier to understand. I have edited the post for my actual problem. By the way, can it be done without `delarray`?

Comment: @antshar No, sorry. I helped you solving the *stated* problem. If *your* problem is different, state the one you have. But don't vandalize your question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad :(